Relay Command Wont Execute
I've reviewed a few other questions on this subject and haven't found a solution.
Databinding is working, I tested with different labels and entry fields to make sure. I am not getting a data binding failure. I am using the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. That said, here is the code.
XAML

<Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Text="Calculate"
       Command="{Binding CalculateValue}"
       FontSize="Small"
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />



 C#   
[RelayCommand]

private void CalculateValue()
{

    TotalValue = 100;
}

I know its binding now because the original snippet gave a binding error because of an error (was public instead of private), but now that that is corrected its simply not executing. I have TotalValue bound to another label within the View and it doesn't update. I've also attempted to use a Breakpoint at the fuction, and no luck there.
One thing that stands out to me (since I looked at examples from MS) is my class is labeled as partial and theirs is not. I get an error if I don't define it as partial (which the documentation says to do) so that makes sense, but the sample they have on Github does not.
Appreciate all the help.

You are right. If you use RelayCommand attribute to annotate the CalculateValue method, it will generate a Command named CalculateValueCommand. Here is the doc: RelayCommand attribute

Found the issue. In the View cs file, I was setting the binding source before
InitializeComponents();

I did this because I got the binding error on the Command if I did it after. I set the BindingContext after Initialize, which brought back the binding error, but then I realized I needed to add 'Command' at the end of the name. Corrected code should look like this.
<Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Text="Calculate"
       Command="{Binding CalculateValueCommand}"
       FontSize="Small"
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />

